# how to install magento 1.9 premium theme to magento 1.7 live website

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, theme, design

Is it possible to install a theme developed for `magento 1.9` version to `magento 1.7` version.I have lot of customization in my current magento website which is magento `version 1.7`.

If can how can i perform this task? Please advice me to update this theme.

Answer (score 1):

Since Magento 1.9 have some changes between Magento 1.9 , Theme you have different files for magento 1.9. One way you can do is to create a dev site from your live site. After that install this theme there. Check all the issues that will happend and fix them.

Upgrading to magento 1.9 would be great, but your customization will broken.